# Weighted Interval Scheduling Variant with "multitasking"

Tags: dynamic-programming

I have a variant of weighted interval scheduling that I couldn't find anything about: the inputs are intervals in which people are present in target area, their importance (the "weight"), and permitted amount of visits to the target area. The output should be the times to visit the target area to meet people of most importance (visit is a single point in time, you meet all people present at the time of visit, if someone is present at multiple visits, they are counted only once).

I tried solving this recursively without any memoization, and it works, but I am sure there must be a better way. Also, does this type of problem have its own name?

Comment: This sounds like a particular case of the [Maximum coverage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem)

Comment: @Stef I think you're right, but the article speaks a lot about approximations and says the problem is NP-hard. Does that mean there isn't an algorithm that would solve this problem in polynomial time?

Comment: I don't know. Your problem is a particular case of maximum coverage: it's maximum coverage, with the additional hypothesis that the elements and sets have this "interval" pattern. Perhaps this added hypothesis is enough to find a polynomial-time algorithm. Perhaps it's not. Unfortunately I don't know good keywords to search for your problem directly ("interval maximum coverage" gives results about a different problem).